# Found lots of these insects on my study desk today. What are these?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, hemiptera

I came home today, switched on the lights and saw many of these running around my study desk. Any help in identifying these little insects? The picture is zoomed in so it doesn't really do justice to how tiny it is.

Approximate Size: 1mm

Location: Mumbai, India

What are these insects ? How do I get rid of them ?

[image]

Additional Images:

[Additional Image 1](https://ibb.co/pxmb3Yd)

[Additional Image 2](https://ibb.co/7YyjHTH)

[Additional Image 3](https://ibb.co/9hTdWL6)

[Additional Image 4](https://ibb.co/n7dn5qB)

[Video 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EwZOR6K5_As6dZJ3IRVdbZOUDWLsKkRb/view?usp=sharing)

[Video 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q59FxFQljY9lGPA4tG1KxsBKwb7458Jh/view?usp=sharing)

Any help in identifying these is really appreciated. We are freaking out crossing our fingers that it is not bedbugs. What are the chances these are baby bed bugs?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! If possible clear, closeup photos of the creature from multiple angles would be helpful — the picture you posted is so blurry I'm not sure how many legs it has! ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: I've zoomed it 2x on my iPhone and this is the clearest view I could get of this insect. I'll see if I can get a few more. 

Also, Is there a way it can be confirmed that it is not a bedbug?

Comment: The "Camera+ 2" app (and probably many others) has macro functionality, so you can take clear close-ups easily. It's free, as far as I recall.

Comment: Added some more photos and a 4k video. Does that help?

Comment: None of those photos seem any clearer to me ... ——— If you are concerned about bed bugs please search on this site — there is an excellent answer that shows pictures of all stages of bed bug development. ———— In general, please do a [search](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/searching) before asking questions as that is more efficient for you and prevents the accumulation of duplicate questions, which just makes more work for the moderators of this site. Thanks!

Comment: From the main photo this looks like a booklouse to me; which one (and there are a lot of them sharing human living spaces) does need a very good photo.  Searching this site for "book louse" or "booklouse" will (if memory serves) lead to at least one thread that either discusses or links to control measures (which may be justified given the numbers mentioned).

Comment: Thank you all ! It was book louse / book lice.